# PowerBIToolkit - Keep getting error: field "credential" not yet prepared so type is still a ForwardRef

Tags: python, powerbi, langchain

I'm trying to use langchain powerBI integration, but I keep getting this error:
*ConfigError: field "credential" not yet prepared so type is still a ForwardRef, you might need to call PowerBIDataset.update_forward_refs()*

This is my code:

`

```
load_dotenv('credentials.env')

os.environ["AZURE_TENANT_ID"] = 
os.environ.get("AZURE_TENANT_ID")
os.environ["AZURE_CLIENT_ID"] = 
os.environ.get("AZURE_CLIENT_ID")
os.environ["AZURE_CLIENT_SECRET"] = 
os.environ.get("AZURE_CLIENT_SECRET")

username=<my_username>
password=<my_password>
bearer_token=<my_token>

llm = AzureChatOpenAI(
        deployment_name='gpt-4',
        temperature=0.5,
        max_tokens=1000,
        streaming=True,
        api_version="2023-12-01-preview"
)

credential = DefaultAzureCredential()

powerbi = PowerBIDataset(
    dataset_id=dataset_id,
    table_names=["Product", "Project"],
    token = bearer_token
)

toolkit = PowerBIToolkit(
    powerbi=powerbi,
    llm=llm,
    output_token_limit = 1000
)

agent_executor = create_pbi_agent(
    llm=llm,
    toolkit=toolkit,
    verbose=True
)
```

`

Things I have tried:

- calling **PowerBIDataset.update_forward_refs()**, result => error: name 'TokenCredential' is not defined
- adding **token = TokenCredential(bearer_token)**, result => error: Protocols cannot be instantiated
- not using credentials field, and **passing only token**, result => error: The agent only sees the table names given by me and cannot get the schemas, this is part of the "thinking" process:

**Now that I know the Product table exists, I can retrieve the schema for it to identify the columns.
Action: schema_powerbi
Action Input: Product
Error while getting table info for Product: 'results'
Observation: unknown
Thought:**